# Vue3 Functional Component render function Primevue Tooltip

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

```
rowTooltip: (createElement, cell, property, context) => {
            return withDirectives(createElement("div",  "any value"), ["tooltip", "is this the tooltip value?", "is this the value actually?", "no this is the value argument"]);
        },
```

how do I render this tooltip directive : https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/tooltip

inside a render function loop inside a functional component with vue3.

I've been trying for hours

added a fork with my problem

Answer (score 2):

vue3 has function **h**

using with setup function:

```
setup() {
  const tooltip = resolveDirective('tooltip');

  return () => {
    const vnode = withDirectives(
      h(Button, { label: "I'am dynamic button, hover me too" }),
      [[tooltip, 'tooltip directive with render function']]
    );

    return vnode;
  };
}
```

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-gg76si?file=src/main.js

Comment: thank you for that answer - this works - as your example shows.

And I've renamed "h" to "createElement" while importing


my issue occurs when I try to do THAT but while inside a render function in a functional component (where you no longer have "this" - as in a proper context)
My theory is that my component no longer has access to "PrimeVue" that I had while instantiating the application - since my functional component is a a standalone instance.


Any idea about that?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-6yjp8d?file=src/components/RenderDynamic.js

Added my own fork of your project to simulate my problem

Comment: @LiadGoren just add defineComponent

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-nq4pcj?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FRenderDynamic.js

Comment: will this still be a stateless functional component?

I'm using this tooltip inside a HUGE framework like Data Tree Table I've built

It is incredibly big and complex so I've refactored it half a year ago to a functional component for performance.

So the component I'm using this in must be functional

Comment: by using the "define component" wrapper I'm losing the performance gained by using a functional component.

as much as your solution is clean and correct for most cases - I must insist on staying stateless and functional.
even if it means there's no solution to this problem